# Drupal PHP block visibility rules based on product in shopping cart

Tags: drupal, attributes, block, cart, ubercart

I wan to use php code to hide or show a block on the cart page if and only if the a particular product attribute is in the cart.

for example, i have a list of blue shoes i have already created as a block, and i want to show it on the cart page if only the the user has a product(bag) with attribute (blue) in the cart.

The condition for showing the block or not depends on the Attribute blue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you asked for but it might get you in the right direction. This will show a block on the checkout page if a given product model# is in the cart.

```
<?php
  global $user;
  if (arg(0) != 'cart' || !empty(arg(1))) return false;
  $cid = ($user->uid) ? null : $_SESSION['uc_cart_id'];
  $items = uc_cart_get_contents($cid);
  $models = array('model1', 'model2');
  foreach ($items as $item) {
    if (in_array($item->model, $models)) return true;
  }
  return false;
?>
```